# Eigenvalues and roots of unity for integer coefficients matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, roots-of-unity

I read the following exercise and I am quite stuck:

> Let $A \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, whose coefficients are in $\mathbb{Z}$. We assume that $A$ has $n$ distinct complex eigenvalues, and that the moduli of these eigenvalues are $\leq 1$. Prove that the eigenvalues are roots of unity.

---

My try : of course $A$ is diagonalizable. I can see that the fact that the moduli of the eigenvalues are $\leq 1$ implies that $(A^k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded, and I think we can deduce from the fact that $A$ has integer coefficients that the eigenvalues have modulus $=1$. But I am not really sure how, and how to deduce that the eigenvalues are roots of unity ? Can we maybe prove that $A^k=I_n$ for some $k$ ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hint: There are only a finite number of matrices with integer coefficients with norm $\leq M$ for fixed $M$.

Comment: @leoli1 So the fact that $(A^k)$ is bounded implies that there exists $k,l$ with $A^{k}=A^l$, so $A^{k-l}=I_n$ and we are done. I cannot believe I missed that, thanks a lot !!

Comment: There is a theorem of Kronecker to the effect that if all the zeros of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients are at most one in modulus, then they are all roots of unity.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Indeed, thanks for the comment ! It is a nice one-lign argument... even if the proof of Kronecker's theorem is less elementary than the direct proof above.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Doesn't the argument above applied to the companion matrix prove Kronecker's theorem?

Comment: @Igor, yes, I was thinking the argument here is a nice way to prove Kronecker.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Hi Gerry, I have been rethinking about your idea to prove Kronecker's theorem using this argument. Just to be sure, how do you exactly prove that if $A$ denotes the companion matrix of the polynomial, the sequence $(A^k)$ is bounded ? In my question, $A$ is diagonalizable but not here : I think you can write $A=D+N$ with Dunford decomposition, then say that $(D^k)$ and $(N^k)$ are bounded, and so is $(A^k)$... Is it correct, is there any other way ? Thanks !

Comment: I guess you can reduce to the case of ireducible polynomials, and then the companion matrix is guaranteed to be diagonalizable (since the eigenvalues are the roots, which are all distinct).

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think I see what you mean : you can write $P$ as a product of irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, and because each factor $Q$ is irreducible, you must have $\gcd(Q,Q')=1$ so $Q$ cannot have multiple roots. Is that the way you were thinking of ? Thanks again !

Comment: That's the way!